# keys(window) does not return all members

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to generate a list of all events (`MouseEvent`, `InputEvent`, etc.). I was thinking I would do this by iterating over all members of `window` and testing for each of them, if they are events.

But I am having problems getting a list of these members. I thought I could use `keys(window)` but it does not return any of the events (fx `MouseEvent`), even though `window.MouseEvent` is defined.

I don't want a list of member names, I need a list of the members themselves. In a format like:

```
arr = [MouseEvent, InputEvent];
```

How do I get such a list?

Comment: You want an array of specific events, or all events?

Comment: I need all events, not just some specific ones.

Comment: why do you need that? since window is a global object, some external frameworks may add other variables that looks like an event. I believe you should take a look to the [events documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) instead and list them manually

Answer (score 0):

This will show you all the `on` events (`onmouseout` etc). Is this what you were looking for?

```
function onThing() {
  return Object.keys(window).filter(function (el) {
    return el.substring(0, 2) === 'on';
  });
}

onThing();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/taa6h0ns/)

Comment: That's `window.__proto__`to get the events